# Can a Jamaican citizen travel to Jamaica from the US with an expired passport and a US green card?

Tags: passports, international-travel, passport-renewals, jamaica, jamaican-citizens

I am a citizen of Jamaica with a valid US permanent resident card. My Jamaican passport has expired and I have tried with no success to renew it through my assigned consulate in the US since December 2017, but each time my passport photos were rejected. I checked with the Jamaican passport and immigration agency and they said I am able to arrive with the expired passport and renew it there. Issue is, will I have any issues ***leaving*** the US to go to my **home** **country** with an expired passport? I will have my US permanent resident card and Jamaican birth certificate if they needed to verify me.

Comment: Can you find a professional passport photo shop that will guarantee your passport photos?  There seems to be at least one in New York, near the Jamaican consulate.  If you're applying by mail, you can look for one in the nearest Jamaican neighborhood, or ask other Jamaicans living in the US where they've had their passport photographs taken.

Comment: Hi Phoog, I reside in Ohio so I mail my documents to New York. I have been to two professional passport places here and both times they have been refused. I was told about the one by the consulate but that would require me flying to NY.

Comment: What Airline will you be flying on? You should contact whatever ground ahndling Company checks in for that Airline at your departure Airport (so not the Airline itself)

Comment: I'm flying southwest and they gave me a generic response. I'll have to see if I can find who the ground handler is

Answer (score 14):

This is what Timatic, the database used by airlines for immigration information, [says](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=JM&DE=KIN&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX):

> Passport required.
>   - Nationals of Jamaica are allowed to enter with an expired passport.
>
> - Warning: if departing from the USA (regardless of any  destination passport exemptions), a valid passport and/or  accepted departure document For details, click here is required by the US immigration authorities.

And the list of departure documents includes a valid US permanent resident card.

So you would be ok on that front. However, the airline may require valid ID to check in, and [TSA requires a valid form of ID to pass through the security checkpoint](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/identification). TSA will accept your permanent residency card if it's valid, so you're ok there, but you may want to allow some extra time at the check-in counter in case there are issues. I would try to get confirmation from the airline, ideally in writing, that this is acceptable to them. Being denied boarding would cause considerable delay and expense.

Comment: I can't imagine any airline refusing to accept a valid US green card as valid identification to check in for a US flight.

Comment: I mean *...for a flight departing from the US,* and with the assumption that the traveler has adequate documents for the destination country.

Comment: OP should get a confirmation from the ground handler, **NOT** the airline